# C# subscribe to events based on parameter type?

Tags: c#

I have a `Commander` class, which handles commands. All these commands implement the `ICommand` interface. Basically the command pattern...

Now I want to create something similar to an `event` for each specific type of command, without actually making an event for each specific type in the commander. The commander should not be coupled to each type of command.

So my command has a method `void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T: ICommand`. If a subscriber calls this with the method `void MyAttackCommandHandler(AttackCommand att)` as the parameter, I expect the subscriber to get a callback only for `AttackCommands`. However another class can also subscribe for a different command.

I tried creating a dictionary, that maps the type of the parameter (the kind of command) to a list of subscribers: `Dictionary<Type, List<Action<ICommand>>> _subscriptions`, and then my subscribe method would look something like:

```
public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback)
    where T: ICommand
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (_subscriptions.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        List<Action<ICommand>> subscribtions = _subscriptions[type];
        subscribtions.Add(callback);
    }
    else ... //create a new entry in _subscriptions
}
```

This however doesn't work because `callback` isn't of the type `Action<ICommand>`, but of `Action<AttackCommand>` for instance.

How would one implement this cleanly?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `AttackCommand` implements `ICommand` right?

Comment: If you have a base class like `BaseCommand` that implements `ICommand` and have `AttackCommand` extending `BaseCommand` that should work ?

Comment: @Rahul That's correct.

Comment: Then it should work just fine since attackcomand is of type Icommand.

Comment: @Rahul No it doesn't. You have it backwards. The problem is that ICommand is not an AttackCommand. (Though AttackCommand is an ICommand :P) So you can't add an Action<AttackCommand> to a list of Action<ICommand>. The list expects all actions in it to accept all kinds of commands, and I try to add an action that only accepts attack commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
subscribtions.Add(i => callback((T)i));
```

If the above doesn't work please provide a full example that shows your problem.
Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Commander C = new Commander();
            C.Subscribe((MyCommand i) => { Console.WriteLine(i.Value); });
            C.Subscribe((SquareMyCommand i) => { Console.WriteLine(i.Value); });
            C.Subscribe((SquareMyCommand i) => { Console.WriteLine("**" + i.Value + "**"); });

            C.Do(new MyCommand(2));//1 callback , Prints 2
            C.Do(new SquareMyCommand(3));//2 callbacks, Prints 9 , **9**
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Commander
    {
        Dictionary<Type, List<Action<ICommand>>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<ICommand>>>();
        public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : ICommand
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);

            List<Action<ICommand>> subscribtions = null;
            dictionary.TryGetValue(type, out subscribtions);
            if (subscribtions == null)
            {
                subscribtions = new List<Action<ICommand>>();
                dictionary.Add(type, subscribtions);
            }
            subscribtions.Add(i => callback((T)i));
        }

        public void Do<T>(T t) where T : ICommand
        {
            foreach (var item in dictionary[t.GetType()])
                item(t);
        }
    }

    public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public MyCommand(int x) { Value = x; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class SquareMyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public SquareMyCommand(int x) { Value = x * x; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    public interface ICommand
    {
        int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might like to add some explanation as to why this works over the question example.