# Check type visibility prior to dynamic double dispatch

Tags: c#, dynamic, access-modifiers, double-dispatch

Implementing double dispatch using `dynamic`:

```
public interface IDomainEvent {}

public class DomainEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly List<Delegate> subscribers = new List<Delegate>();

    public void Subscribe<TEvent>(Action<TEvent> subscriber) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        subscribers.Add(subscriber);
    }

    public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent domainEvent) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        foreach (Action<TEvent> subscriber in subscribers.OfType<Action<TEvent>>())
        {
            subscriber(domainEvent);
        }
    }

    public void PublishQueue(IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
    {
        foreach (IDomainEvent domainEvent in domainEvents)
        {
            // Force double dispatch - bind to runtime type.
            Publish(domainEvent as dynamic);
        }
    }
}

public class ProcessCompleted : IDomainEvent { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

Works in most cases:

```
var dispatcher = new DomainEventDispatcher();

dispatcher.Subscribe((ProcessCompleted e) => Console.WriteLine("Completed " + e.Name));

dispatcher.PublishQueue(new [] { new ProcessCompleted { Name = "one" },
                                 new ProcessCompleted { Name = "two" } });
```

> Completed one
>
> Completed two

But if the subclasses are not visible to the dispatch code, this results in a runtime error:

```
public static class Bomb
{
    public static void Subscribe(DomainEventDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher.Subscribe((Exploded e) => Console.WriteLine("Bomb exploded"));
    }
    public static IDomainEvent GetEvent()
    {
        return new Exploded();
    }
    private class Exploded : IDomainEvent {}
}
// ...

Bomb.Subscribe(dispatcher);  // no error here
// elsewhere, much later...
dispatcher.PublishQueue(new [] { Bomb.GetEvent() });  // exception
```

> RuntimeBinderException
>
> The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEvent' in the generic type or method 'DomainEventDispatcher.Publish(TEvent)'

This is a contrived example; a more realistic one would be an event that is internal to another assembly.

How can I prevent this runtime exception? If that isn't feasible, how can I detect this case in the `Subscribe` method and fail fast?

**Edit:** Solutions that eliminate the dynamic cast are acceptable, so long as they do not require a Visitor-style class that knows about all of the subclasses.

Comment: From what I understand you just need to subscribe to events based on the parameter type,right? In this case the question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581701/c-sharp-subscribe-to-events-based-on-parameter-type/34581806#34581806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is change your Publish method to:

```
foreach(var subscriber in subscribers) 
    if(subscriber.GetMethodInfo().GetParameters().Single().ParameterType == domainEvent.GetType())
         subscriber.DynamicInvoke(domainEvent);
```

**Update**
You also have to change the call to

```
 Publish(domainEvent); //Remove the as dynamic
```

This way you don't have to change Publish's signature

I prefer my other answer though:
[C# subscribe to events based on parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581701/c-sharp-subscribe-to-events-based-on-parameter-type/34581806#34581806)

**Update 2**
About your question

> I am curious as to why this dynamic invocation works where my original
>   one fails.

Keep in mind that dynamic is not a special type.
Basically the compiler:
1)Replaces  it with object
2)Refactors you code to more complicated code
3)Removes compile time checks (these checks are done in runtime )

If you try to replace

```
Publish(domainEvent as dynamic);
```

with

```
Publish(domainEvent as object);
```

You will get the same message ,but this time in compile time.
The error message is self explanatory:

> The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEvent' in the
>   generic type or method 'DomainEventDispatcher.Publish(TEvent)'

**As a final note.**
**dynamic was designed for specific scenarios,99,9% of the time you don't need it and you can replace it with statically typed code.

If you think you need it(like the above case) you are probably doing something wrong**

Comment: This does appear to work with my simple example. I also had to change the method signature to `public void Publish(IDomainEvent domainEvent)`, I am curious as to why this dynamic invocation works where my original one fails.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I prevent this runtime exception?

You really can't, that's the nature of `dynamic`.

> If that isn't feasible, how can I detect this case in the `Subscribe` method and fail fast?

You could probably check `typeof(TEvent).IsPublic` before adding the subscriber.

That said, I'm not sure you really need `dynamic` for double dispatch. What if `subscribers` were a `Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IDomainEvent>>>` and you looked up subscribers in `Publish(IDomainEvent domainEvent)` based on `domainEvent.GetType()`?

Comment: Thanks Keith! I did find that `Action<IDomainEvent>` does not work - `T` in `Action<T>` is contravariant, so `Add` fails.

Comment: Because of this I'm not sure how to invoke the `Delegate` returned from the dictionary/list.

Comment: `IsVisible` appears to work better than `IsPublic` in testing. That's an option; the downside is it disallows `internal` (to this assembly) events.

Comment: @dahlbyk Your answer is not correct,but your suggestion is

Comment: The trick is in what @GeorgeVovos linked to: `Add(i => subscriber((TEvent)i))`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to figure out why the dynamic call fails, I would concentrate on providing a working solution, because the way I understand the contract, you have a valid subscriber, hence you should be able to dispatch the calls to it.

Fortunately there are a couple non dynamic call based solutions.

**Invoking `Publish` method via reflection:**

```
private static readonly MethodInfo PublishMethod = typeof(DomainEventDispatcher).GetMethod("Publish"); // .GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Publish" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition);

public void PublishQueue(IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
{
    foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
    {
        var publish = PublishMethod.MakeGenericMethod(domainEvent.GetType());
        publish.Invoke(this, new[] { domainEvent });
    }
}
```

**Invoking `subscriber` via reflection:**

```
public void PublishQueue(IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
{
    foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
    {
        var eventType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(domainEvent.GetType());
        foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
        {
            if (eventType.IsAssignableFrom(subscriber.GetType()))
                subscriber.DynamicInvoke(domainEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Invoking `Publish` method via precompiled cached delegate:**

```
private static Action<DomainEventDispatcher, IDomainEvent> CreatePublishFunc(Type eventType)
{
    var dispatcher = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DomainEventDispatcher), "dispatcher");
    var domainEvent = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IDomainEvent), "domainEvent");
    var call = Expression.Lambda<Action<DomainEventDispatcher, IDomainEvent>>(
        Expression.Call(dispatcher, "Publish", new [] { eventType },
            Expression.Convert(domainEvent, eventType)),
        dispatcher, domainEvent);
    return call.Compile();
}

private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<DomainEventDispatcher, IDomainEvent>> publishFuncCache = new Dictionary<Type, Action<DomainEventDispatcher, IDomainEvent>>();

private static Action<DomainEventDispatcher, IDomainEvent> GetPublishFunc(Type eventType)
{
    lock (publishFuncCache)
    {
        Action<DomainEventDispatcher, IDomainEvent> func;
        if (!publishFuncCache.TryGetValue(eventType, out func))
            publishFuncCache.Add(eventType, func = CreatePublishFunc(eventType));
        return func;
    }
}

public void PublishQueue(IEnumerable<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
{
    foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
    {
        var publish = GetPublishFunc(domainEvent.GetType());
        publish(this, domainEvent);
    }
}
```

The delegates are lazily created and cached on demand using compiled  `System.Linq.Expressions`.

This method so far should be the fastest. It also is the closest to the dynamic call implementation, with the difference that it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Since your `Subscribe` method already has the generic type, you can make this easy change:

```
private readonly List<Action<object>> subscribers = new List<Action<object>>();

public void Subscribe<TEvent>(Action<TEvent> subscriber) where TEvent : class
{
    subscribers.Add((object evnt) =>
    {
        var correctType = evnt as TEvent;
        if (correctType != null)
        {
            subscriber(correctType);
        }
    });
}

public void Publish(object evnt)
{
    foreach (var subscriber in subscribers)
    {
        subscriber(evnt);
    }
}
```

If you are missing the compile-time type information on both the publish- and the subscribe-side, you can still eliminate the dynamic cast. See this [Expression building example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931278/644812)